# How to Jump to next Element in Dart Lists, (forLoops)

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, emoji, dart-pub

Hey Darting Developers, I want to Seek help. I am Currently Making a Emoji Translator, here i am Getting a Problem that,

```
List emojis = [
["Happy", "Smile", "Wink", "Tickle"], 
["Silent", "Depressed", "Cry", "Sad"], 
["lichi", "apple", "kiwi", "Banana"]];
```

1. I have a Long List
2. This List is under a List.
3. I want to Seek only 3 Items from a List.
4. And then Jump out to Other Item of the Big List.

How to Get Three Items and then Get out of loop and Get inside the another List. and so on.
This Question is Bit hard to Understand, but I need to Seek help.

Comment: "How to Get Three Items" - `emojis.take(3).toList()`

Comment: @pskink I loved this, Actaully its working good, But What if i need to Print all of the Item of whole List, (only Three) then.?

Comment: i dont know what you mean by that

Comment: What if i need to Print only three items of Baby list all Parent List. Can ou explain em  with For loop, @pskink

Comment: Do not hesitate to draw a little scheme when you know that your question is not very clear! It will help us to give you a precise answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to map over the emojis 2D list and take the first 3 elements.

```
final emojis = [
  ["Happy", "Smile", "Wink", "Tickle"], 
  ["Silent", "Depressed", "Cry", "Sad"], 
  ["lichi", "apple", "kiwi", "Banana"]
];
  
final transformedList = emojis.map((sublist) => sublist.take(3).toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
emojis.forEach((subList) {
  for(int i=0; i<subList.length; i++){
    if(i > 2) break;
    
    //get your first 3 items
  }
});
```

Comment: Jim, I am Getting erros while implementing it, I want you to See my Small code which i am currently working on. So to Best Implement this in my Programme.